# CPP memory leaks detection tool for Mac Mojave

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am developing with c++ with a mac. Frequently, my codes have memory leak issues, and I want a tool that can detect them. I want something like Valgrind, but I can't use Valgrind as I'm on Mojave(10.14.4, Darwin 18) and the user created patch doesn't compile. Any recommendations?

Comment: I don't know of anything to beat Valgrind. Personally, I would spin up a VM or Docker container just to use it

Comment: Welcome to developer experience on MacOS the cradle of innovation!